# Mysql Select and compare between row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've stucked in making expression, cause i don't know how to make proper query command.

here is what i wanted to do :

```
Member Table 
member_id ----- member_name ----- late
1         ----- John        -----   0
2         ----- Doe         -----   4
3         ----- Dennis      -----   6


Type Table
type_id ----- type_name ----- ctr
1       -----  Good     -----  1
2       -----  Bad      -----  3
3       -----  Very Bad -----  5
```

I wanted to rate them according how many time they late,

if their late equal or less than 1 they will be considered good

if their late equal or more than 3 they will be considered bad

if their late equal or more than 4 they will be considered very bad

how do i make query that give result like this:

```
John   ----- Good
Doe    ----- Bad
Dennis ----- Very Bad
```

Comment: Does the `late` column relate to the `type_id` column? Your question needs more detail

Comment: Any explanation on why the desired result is like it is?

Comment: Dennis  late =3.   Why "Bad"?   For others it seems a simple join.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know how to make a proper table relation.
But according table that i've build, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this (you have to modify your TYPE table, adding CTR_START and CTR_END):

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBER_TABLE (MEMBER_ID INT, MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(20), LATE INT)
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE VALUES (1,'John', 0);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE VALUES (2,'Doe', 4);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE VALUES (3,'Dennis', 6);

CREATE TABLE TYPE_TABLE (TYPE_ID INT, TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(20), CTR_START INT, CTR_END INT)
INSERT INTO TYPE_TABLE VALUES (1,'Good', 0,2);
INSERT INTO TYPE_TABLE VALUES (2,'Bad', 3,4);
INSERT INTO TYPE_TABLE VALUES (3,'Very Bad', 5,999);


SELECT A.MEMBER_NAME, B.TYPE_NAME
FROM MEMBER_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TYPE_TABLE B ON A.late>= B.CTR_START AND A.LATE<=B.CTR_END;
```

Output:

```
MEMBER_NAME TYPE_NAME
John    Good
Doe     Bad
Dennis  Very Bad
```

Comment: i'm sorry but would you explain how to make proper table design for this case

Comment: thank you very much, that's what i wanted to do. i'm not defining min and max value in the type_table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly but:

```
SELECT m.member_name, t.type_name
FROM members m JOIN types t ON m.late = t.type_id
```